# Azure Functions in .NET 7 (isolated) published to Azure, 0 functions loaded

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Function (isolated) with .NET 7 to MS Azure using a GitHub Actions workflow. Everything seems to run fine, but for some reason, the Function is not loaded when I deploy it to the cloud. When I run the function local host, everything is fine (works on my machine), once deployed it doesn't.

```cs
public class DemoFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public DemoFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DemoFunction>();
    }

    [Function("DemoFunction")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString("Demo function works!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

The Function App contains only a single function with an HTTP binding (no authentication, anonymous requests allowed). I use Bicep to deploy infra and GH Actions to deploy the Function App. Log Analytics shows this:
[image]

So for some reason it does find the function, but not load it. If I navigate to the Functions blade in the Azure Portal I don't see any function. The project is just a POC project and hosted publicly available at https://github.com/nikneem/function-deployment-with-gh-actions

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh wow, I found the answer in the deployment process. In my GitHub Actions workflow, I did a `dotnet publish` of the Azure Functions project to an output folder. I zipped the content of the output folder and published that zip file as a workflow artifact.

Then in the deployment, I downloaded the workflow artifact (e.g. that zip file) and did a Zip Deployment using that zip file.

Now apparently, something went wrong with this zip file, so I removed that manual zip action, mainly because I found out the deployment step in the GitHub Action also works when you pass a folder containing all published files in.

So the publish step in my GH Actions workflow now looks like this:

```yaml
publish-functions:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: versionize
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: "7.0.x"
    - name: Restore packages
      working-directory: src
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Publish functions app
      working-directory: src
      run: dotnet publish $FUNCTIONS_PATH/$FUNCTIONS_PROJECT -c Release --no-restore -o functionsout /p:Version=${{needs.versionize.outputs.semver}}
    - name: Upload functions artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: player-functions
        path: src/functionsout/*
```

and the deployment step looks like this:

```yaml
deploy-function-app:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: [publish-functions, deploy-infrastructure-prod]
  steps:
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: player-functions
        path: function
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_PROD}}
    - name: Deploy Azure Functions app
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      with:
        app-name: ${{needs.deploy-infrastructure-prod.outputs.functionResourceName}}
        package: function
```

Taking a peek at the logs that the deployment process produces, it will still create a zip file and deploy that. But this is a different zip file than I created manually. All works fine now ;)

Comment: I had the same problem and the answer led to the solution. My zip command was omitting the `.azurefunctions` hidden folder.
After changing my command to include that folder, deployments worked also using my archives

Answer (score 1):

As per the note in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#net-isolated-worker-process-project):

> To be able to publish your isolated function project to either a Windows or a Linux function app in Azure, you must set a value of dotnet-isolated in the remote FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME application setting. To support zip deployment and running from the deployment package on Linux, you also need to update the linuxFxVersion site config setting to DOTNET-ISOLATED|7.0. To learn more, see Manual version updates on Linux.

I can see the relevant configuration settings appear to be set correctly in the infrastructure template with the exception of `linuxFxVersion` - this doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere and the cicd workflow does appear to be performing a zip deployment.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer. I HAD this DOTNET-ISOLATED in, but it kept failing on deployment. Thanks to your post, I found linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet-isolated|7.0' works (so lowercase). It is in the template now, but this doesn't solve my problem, still 1 function found, 0 functions loaded...

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I was getting Bad Gateway (502) error, local deployment works fine.
Finally I found the reason for the problem. .NET version configured in the deployed solution was different from the expected version. It suppose to be configured as .Net Framework v4.8, instead by default it was set to .NET 6 (LTS ) Isolated.
Once it was changed to .NET Framework v4.8, Function App is started working fine.